# Web API 2.2 and OData V4 Route Conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, odata

I upgraded to OData V4 and I realised the routing conventions have changed. So instead of

```
http://somesite.com/api/products/1
```

You would have the following

```
http://somesite.com/api/products(1)
```

Now this is fine for new apps going forward, but we need to support the traditional url's for legacy apps. Is there a way to support both url's, or the traditional url for the time being?

If I have the following example

```
[ODataRoute("{key}")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Put([FromODataUri] string key, Dealer dealer)
{
    // some logic code here        
}
```

I get the following error

```
The path template '{key}' on the action 'Put' in controller 'Dealers' is not a valid OData path template. Resource not found for the segment '{key}'
```

Comment: Have you tried `[ODataRoute("Products/{key}")]`?

Comment: Ya I have - still same issue.

Comment: In OData URL convention, only http://somesite.com/api/products(1) are supported. I'm not sure "http://somesite.com/api/products/1" is what you can with previous version of OData. You mentioned you "upgrade" to OData V4, are you upgrading from old OData version or pure Web API ?

Comment: I was previously using Web Api and decorating the controllers with the Queryable attribute. I recently switched to inheriting from the OdataController. Problem with Web Api and the attribute is getting $count to work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are switching to `OData v4` from an earlier version, there are several breaking changes.. i.e. for example, v3 clients will not be able to consume the response returned by a v4 service... Hence uri may be the least of your problems..

If you need to support existing clients.. then your only option would be to host two versions of the same service.